# Is it possible to reset/discard values fetched by Firebase Remote Config?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I have created a layer on top of Firebase Remote Config that my app uses to decide whether feature are on or off, or to get custom values. I've written some unit tests around this. But it seems like when people use the app and get values from the network, they are saved and override the default values that you set on the `FIRRemoteConfig` with `setDefaults`. This causes issues with my unit tests.

Is there a way you can tell `FIRRemoteConfig` to forget about the values it has saved and just use the default values you set on it?

Comment: I'm surprised there's no API for this. It's a very valid request.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [doc here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-ios#fetch-andactivate-values-from-the-server-as-needed) to fetch the value from server and use them you need to:

1. call the `fetchWithCompletionHandler:` or `fetchWithExpirationDuration:completionHandler:` function
2. call `activateFetched`

What you could do for your unit test is: use a fresh install, *comment / remove* the `activateFetched` function call, and it'll return the default value you have set up.

Answer (score 0):

The goal of the fetched values are to override your defaults, which are basically there in case the user can't connect to the firebase servers and fetch the config.

What you need to do is to either:

1. Do not activate your fetched values on the Unit test, this would leave your default values as they are. This would need you to alter your app logic to check if you are in the unit test.
2. define a user property (ie "test_run") and setup your remote config to return real values only for users with this value on false  and the values you need for testing when true, which is cleaner.

I have some concerns about the validity a test that doesn't use real values though.